# How do I use split on spaces and tabulations?

Tags: python, string, list, split, key

I am currently trying to create a game for my class of programming. However, I can't figure out how to split the following string sequence:

```
map:
39 41
hubs:
21 3 1500 25
21 38 1500 25
peaks:
10 10 200
11 10 300
12 10 400
10 11 200
10 12 500
```

Once I split that, I am left with a list but I'm having trouble using it.

```
['map:', '39', '41', 'hubs:', '21', '3', '1500', '25', '21', '38', '1500', '25', 'peaks:', '10', '10', '200', '11', '10', '300', '12', '10', '400', '10', '11', '200', '10', '12', '500']
```

Ideally, I would like to turn that list into a dictionary but how do I chose **map**, **hubs** and **peaks** as keys? I know my question is maybe silly but I'm stuck and could really use some help :) Thank you!
(we are not allowed to import any modules aside from math, random,..)

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are not going to do all your homework.

Comment: Do you have definitely have empty lines in your file or is that just a consequence of a copy/paste here? What would this dictionary with 3 keys look like - what would be the values?

Comment: I know haha that's not what I'm asking! :) Once I split that, I have a list that reads "map:","39","41",...; and i'm having trouble putting that in a dictionnary. How exactly do I choose which words are keys and which are data?

Comment: Show us the code you already have!

Comment: You loop over the file and when a line ends with a `:` then it's the key you want to use until you find another one... when then you set as that keys values is unclear... given the example input could you [edit] your post to include what the *output* you desire would be for that and the logic behind it?

Comment: @JonClements I think that's due to the copy/paste, I just joined this website and I am still trying to figure it out, sorry :). I am supposed to end up having the first two numbers of each line as the coordinates of the unit, and the other numbers would be health points, in this case. I am just having trouble associating each number and word to its role, if that makes sense

Comment: Also... for what you're trying to do... the `math` and `random` modules make no sense whatsoever... it kind of seems like you've got a task here that we're only getting a tiny bit of the picture of...

Comment: @SolèneMehaudens so... is there a blank line after each "header" (and one after the last entry for that header) or are there no blank lines at all? Could you try and fix your code block to make that clear please

Comment: @JonClements fixed it! No blank lines, but there are tabulations after each word and each line represents a different unit. And I know those modules are not useful here but I have looked at other questions before writing mine and I saw that some of the people commenting advised to use other modules so I just wanted to specify that I couldn't do that here, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of the last key in a variable and add to that key's value on subsequent lines (that are not keys):

```
lines = """map:
39 41
hubs:
21 3 1500 25
21 38 1500 25
peaks:
10 10 200
11 10 300
12 10 400
10 11 200
10 12 500""".split("\n")

# with open('plateau.txt','r') as f:
#     lines = f.read().split("\n")

d = dict()
currentKey = None
for line in lines:
    if ":" in line:
        currentKey    = line.strip(":")
        d[currentKey] = []
    else:
        d[currentKey].append(tuple(line.split(" ")))
```

result:

```
print(d)

{
   'map':   [('39', '41')],
   'hubs':  [('21', '3', '1500', '25'), ('21', '38', '1500', '25')],
   'peaks': [('10', '10', '200'), ('11', '10', '300'), ('12', '10', '400'),
             ('10', '11', '200'), ('10', '12', '500')]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split a string by calling the split() function. For example, you have a string and want to split it into a list separating the word with a comma or say in this case space.

```
string1 = 'This is for an example'

list_of_string1 = string1.split(' ')
```

so now the list_of string variable is set ['This', 'is', 'for', 'an', 'example.']

Note that '.' is still there as you splitted by a space or ' '.
I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading this line by line from a file, you could simply check whether the line ends in a `:` to decide whether it's a key or a value.

When you see a new key, add it to the dict and set the value to an empty list, but keep the list around so you can keep appending to it as you see new values.

When the line is not a key, you can use `split()` on it and use a list comprehension to cast the items as integer numbers. You can turn them into tuples so you'll have a list of tuples for each key.

Something like this should work:

```
result = {}
# initialize `values` to None, so you get an
# error if you see values before a key.
values = None
with open('description.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # remove newline, spaces
        if not line:
            continue  # skip blank lines
        if line.endswith(':'):
            # it's a key. strip the `:` and start a new list
            values = []
            result[line.rstrip(':')] = values
        else:
            values.append(tuple(int(i) for i in line.split()))
```

One part of this code that might look odd to beginners is how the values are magically being added to the right key. This works because a Python list is an object in memory, so storing it in `values` *and* in `results['peaks']` means they're both pointing to the same list object, so appending to `values` will correctly add it to the list of peaks.

The syntax of the list comprehension (more of a tuple comprehension here) might also look complex, but it's in fact a very pythonic construct and what in fact makes Python so pleasant to use, how you can express that complex idea so succinctly.

Running this code on your sample data produces the following result:

```
{'map': [
    (39, 41)],
 'hubs': [
    (21, 3, 1500, 25),
    (21, 38, 1500, 25)],
 'peaks': [
    (10, 10, 200),
    (11, 10, 300),
    (12, 10, 400),
    (10, 11, 200),
    (10, 12, 500)]}
```

I imagine this is what you had in mind, or at least close to it.